# A way to speed up 19 calls to geopandas.read_file()?

Tags: python, asynchronous, geopandas

I have some(one else's) code that is calling `geopandas.read_file()` to read 19 shapefiles totaling about 2.7G that's taking about a minute to run, and I'd like to know if there's any way to speed it up.

The only thing I've thought of is trying to load the 19 shapefiles asynchronously, but it seems like I'd have to fork geopandas and make my own read function to do that.

Would anyone know if an easier way?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Or is it possible to use `geopandas.read_file()` with the asyncio module?

Comment: There probably is, but we can't do much with this little information.

Comment: That's pretty good performance to read 2.7G (50M a second). Do you need all of the shapefiles in one process? You could create a small thread pool to do the read_file and get a bit of overlap.

Answer (score 2):

You may get a performance boost with threads where you'd get some overlap in the read/process cycles and parallel execution when geopandas is doing work in a C extension without the global interpreter lock (GIL). I don't think it will be dramatic but worth a try

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.pool
import geopandas

files_to_read = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

# guessing a max of 4 threads would be reasonable since much of read_file
# will likely be done in a C extension without the GIL
pool=mp.pool.ThreadPool(min(mp.cpu_count(), len(files_to_read), 4))
frames = pool.map(geopandas.read_file, files_to_read, chunksize=1)
pool.close()
```

Comment: Thanks much! Would you know why this seems to run fine on Python 2.7.16, but on Python 3.6.10 (Anaconda) and 3.7.3 I'm encountering this error?

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "stackoverflow.py", line 9, in <module>`
    `pool=mp.pool.ThreadPool(min(mp.cpu_count, len(files_to_read), 4))`
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'method'`

Comment: That was a bug... should have been `mp.cpu_count()`. Capping at 4 subprocesses was also somewhat arbitrary, you could experiment with that.